# Pandas - Add a column level to multi index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to add a sublevel (L4) in my dataframe, based on a list of values:

```
x = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02]
```

The df.columns returns me this:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Foo', 'Bar'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=['L1', 'L2', 'L3'])
```

So far I have tried that:

```
df = pd.concat([df], keys=x, names=['L4'], axis=1).swaplevel(i='L4', j='L1', axis=1).swaplevel(i='L4', j='L2', axis=1).swaplevel(i='L4', j='L3', axis=1)
```

but it doesn't give the good value, it repeats list_levels[0] (0.01).

Do you have any idea on how I can do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Foo', 'Bar'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
       names=['L1', 'L2', 'L3'])

pd.DataFrame(columns = cols).T\
  .assign(x = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02])\
  .set_index('x', append=True).T
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataFrame with the column index as the Index, and the `data` being the level you want to add, as `set_index(append=True)` is only defined for the row Index. Then assign it with `df.columns = ...`

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Foo', 'Bar'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a']],
                codes=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
                names=['L1', 'L2', 'L3'])
x = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02]

pd.DataFrame(x, index=idx, columns=['L4']).set_index('L4', append=True).index
#MultiIndex([('Foo', 'A', 'a', 0.01),
#            ('Foo', 'B', 'a', 0.01),
#            ('Foo', 'C', 'a', 0.01),
#            ('Bar', 'A', 'a', 0.02),
#            ('Bar', 'B', 'a', 0.02),
#            ('Bar', 'C', 'a', 0.02)],
#           names=['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4'])
```

---

Under the hood `set_index` just recreates the entire MultiIndex when appending, so a more hands-on approach is

```
arrays = []
for i in range(idx.nlevels):
    arrays.append(idx.get_level_values(i))

arrays.append(pd.Index(x, name='L4'))  # Add the new level

new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
#MultiIndex([('Foo', 'A', 'a', 0.01),
#            ('Foo', 'B', 'a', 0.01),
#            ('Foo', 'C', 'a', 0.01),
#            ('Bar', 'A', 'a', 0.02),
#            ('Bar', 'B', 'a', 0.02),
#            ('Bar', 'C', 'a', 0.02)],
#           names=['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4'])
```